# Summary Level Formula - Sum Closed/Won Opportunities

Tags: apex, formula, reporting, custom-report-type, summary

I am using Lightning and trying to build a summary level formula field to show the sum of closed/won opps next to the sum of total opportunities for a given time period (fiscal quarter for example).

Psuedo-code :

```
IF( StageName = "Closed/Won", AMOUNT:SUM, "")
```

I am not sure of how to write this formula here, but the idea is that I want to sum up all opportunities which it does by default,but add the summary level formula to sum up closed won opportunities next to it.

Comment: I am not sure why this has been downvoted.  I tried to put together a formula to achieve this.  I also did read the docs on the salesforce site, but they are more general in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this in two steps

Step 1 - Create a Row Level Formula called `Amount Won`

```
IF (ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed/Won',Amount,0)
```

Step 2 - Create a Summary Level Formula that sums the row level formula. SFDC will generate this for you from the UX. You will have to scroll to the bottom of the left hand field list pane to see the row level formula

```
CDF1:SUM
```

As an alternative to Step 1, you could create a Formula field on Opportunity that looks as I described in Step 1. This frees up room for a row level formula on the report

Answer (score 0):

`IF(ISPICKVAL(StageName,'Closed/Won',Amount,0)` is missing a ) and it should be something like `IF(ISPICKVAL(STAGE_NAME,'Closed Won'),AMOUNT,0)` where the actual name of the won stage is unique to your Salesforce account. Thanks for the original post btw...it really helped me.